# ERROR/ZestADZAdView SDK(30873): Caught IOException in fetchConfig() when integrate Zest with adwhirl in android

Tags: android, ads, adwhirl, zest

I'm not receiving any ads while using Zest (Komli) AdNw with Adwhirl
and the code fires this excpetion..
Can anyone tell me why??

Like any adNw ..i just put the SDK in the application..declaring Needed Permsissons..then requesting the ads..
It works fine with Admob..

```
    LinearLayout adLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads);
        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "Key");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adLayout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
//        AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(true);
        adLayout.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening in the source [here](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/source/browse/src/com/adwhirl/AdWhirlManager.java?repo=sdk-android#202), somewhere in the method that is just trying to fetch the config and convert the response json into a String.  It looks like an issue with configuring your ids in AdWhirl.  Try hitting

> http://mob.adwhirl.com/getInfo.php?appver=311&appid=YOUR_APP_KEY

and replacing `YOUR_APP_KEY` with your actual app key.  See if you find something out of the ordinary in the response.